# Is it true that broken bone will never recover/restore its previous strength?

Tags: bones, broken-bones, recovery, bone-density

Is it true that broken bone will never return to its former state and regain its previous strength. I don't mean that it will be overly weak and fragile.

Is the statement that a healed bone has a higher probability to break in the place of previous injury if the bone again experiences similar excessive stress pressure legit?

Comment: I have heard quite the opposite. I have heard that a broken bone actually has increased strength and is more likely to break in a different area from where it was previously broken(in other words fractures stimulate bone growth like exercise stimulates muscle growth)